# How to create an executable program for windows through a PHP file?

Tags: php, executable, phar

Is it possible to convert a PHP PHAR file to an executable application?

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple ways to do this :

- `.bat` file that executes your PHAR file

OR

- Write a program with a compiled language (C, C++ etc.) that executes your PHAR (via system commands) file and compile it